Should I somehow seal/protect perforations made to feed Cat6 cable in basement ceiling?
I’ve installed a wireless AP (PoE) in the ceiling in my basement. I only put a small hole big enough for the cable to go through and mounted the AP right below it so the hole is not visible. no patch, no caulk, no feed-through bushel. Should I have done something differently? I don’t think I need a box for low voltage network cable. Asking since I’m planning to install a small camera in a similar fashion.
I’m in Ontario, Canada in case that matters. The AP is one of those disk shaped ones. The camera would also be PoE.

Is the AP plugged into house (120v) power? If so, please describe how that’s put together.

I would have put the AP somewhere you can ... ahem ... Access it physically when necessary. Other than that quibble, it it works it must be possible.

Sorry I missed that part. The AP is powered via PoE from a PoE switch. The AP is not inside the ceiling, only the cable. I can reach the ap with no issues. I left a bit of slack in the cable so I could terminate it while standing on the ground (ceiling is at 7’6’ or 225cm high)

What's on the other side of the hole?

If the area above the ceiling tiles is used as the cold air return path (you'll see this often in office buildings) then you'll need CAT cable specifically for plenum.  But otherwise, no box is electrically necessary.

return path is ducted, I checked that when I notice the cost difference between plenum rated vs regular riser cables. As for what is at the other side of the hole, only the above level sub-floor, no electricity or water, a bit close to an air duct (several inches)

The question here isn't clear. Are you asking whether Cat6 can run through drywall (or whatever your ceiling is) without protection, or are you asking whether the connections need to be in a box? Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question and not just list the general topic.

Fair comment, title updated. Hope this one is better

This is OK. However, my general recommendation is not to use factory-made patch cables for any permanent installations like that, and not to make your own patch cables either. Instead, punch the cable onto a jack. The jack can be installed either in a surface mount box or in a standard single-gang plate in a "box eliminator". Mount the access point directly underneath the jack with a short patch cable.

sounds reasonable, Thanks. I though about adding a box, but ended up reasoning it would make flush install difficult unless I monted it a few inches appart (but then the patchcable would be visible).
